# Exchanges Count at Camel Endpoint

Tags: java, apache-camel

I've a timer route. When the period config on the route elapses, I'd like calculate the number of exchanges at a specified endpoint.

I've been searching fora way to achieve this in vain. I'll appreciate any info that can help me achieve this. My timer route config is as shown:

from("timer://controller?fixedRate=true&period=5000").to("ref:routesManager")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Camel has a ton of information in JMX. So you can grab the stats from there
http://camel.apache.org/camel-jmx.html

Comment: Thanks, Claus. I've developed a management  client using JMX recently,but i was hoping that there exists a non-JMX way to achieve this. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: You can use the controlbus - from Camel 2.11.1 you can also get performance stats: http://camel.apache.org/controlbus.html

Comment: Control Bus is an easy way of achieving this. Having tried both Control Bus and JMX approaches, I settled on JMX as it fits my requirements better. But its good to know I have an option when I start my next project. Thanks a lot.